# Podbean API Publish New Episode invalid type

Tags: php, api, podcast

I'm trying to publish new podcasts via the api, I've successfully upload the mp3 and jpg, which gives 600 seconds to then publish. The podcast 'type' is required and one of the acceptable values is 'public. Here the response:

```
{"error":"input_params_invalid","error_description":"Episode type is invalid."}
```

I'm doing this in PHP. I've been successfully connecting to the API, it is not a token issue.

```
 $params = [
        'access_token'=> $token,
        'type' => 'public',
        'apple_episode_typeoptional' => 'full',
        'status' => 'publish',
        'media_key' => $files['audio'],
        'logo_key' => $files['image'],
        'title' => 'Good day',
        'content' => 'Time you <b>enjoy</b> wasting, was not wasted.'
    ];

    $params = http_build_query($params);

     // . '?' . $params,
    // CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?' . $params,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
    ];
    $response = $this->getPodbean($options);
```

UPDATE:

This is what is holding me up. I don't think I have converted curl -v -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -T /your/path/file.ext "{presigned_url}" correctly. I added CURLOPT_USERPWD because without it I was getting a 403, now I get 400. I added token for good measure but it doesn't seem to affect anything one way or the other.

```
$imageMime = mime_content_type($image_path);

$filename = basename($image_path);
$cfile = curl_file_create($image_path, $imageMime, $filename);

//Open the file using fopen.
$fileHandle = fopen($image_path, 'r');

$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $presigned_url,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$this->client_id:$this->client_secret",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(['image_upload' => $cfile, 'access_token'=> $token]),
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => http_build_query(['Content-Type' => $imageMime]),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
];

$this->getPodbean($options);
```

Comment: _"I've been successfully connecting to the API, it is not a token issue."_ - that seems rather surprising, because are not currently sending any POST data in the request body, but you appended it all to the URL instead.

Comment: http://developers.podbean.com/podbean-api-docs/#api-Episode-Publish_New_Episode says, _"The episode type you can publish is based on the allow_episode_type of the Podbean object allow_episode_type returned by the Get Podcast you invoke."_ - have you verified you are allowed to publish as `public` according to this?

Comment: CBroa, yes I did, I'm retrieving the Podcast object and 'public' is an option. I also tried the postfields and I was getting a more cryptic error.  Further investigation has revealed that it does not appear the files are actually uploading when I use 

$url = 'https://api.podbean.com/v1/files/uploadAuthorize'; 

But there is no response saying this is the case, and why. I've tried relative paths, absolute paths, and URLs to the image and mp3, but it still doesn't work. Obviously I'm missing something in the process. I'm following these instructions:

Comment: https://help.podbean.com/support/solutions/articles/25000008051-publishing-a-new-podcast-episode-via-podbean-api

"If a file is uploaded successfully, you will get a file key in response."

Which I do get but here is the response I get when I try to publish the episode.

{"error":"file_upload_failed","error_description":"File upload failed, please try again later."}

Comment: And `$files['audio']` and `$files['image']` now actually contain those file keys you got from the file uploading API?

Comment: This was missing from the document I've been following. What I'm not sure about is how to convert the CURL to PHP:----
curl -v -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -T /your/path/file.ext "{presigned_url}"
----
1. Episode Publishing Process
The process of publishing/editing episode media file/logo :

Invoking api presigned_url of the returning values will be obtained by connecting to Authorize file upload

Use presigned_url to upload file.

for curl example:

  curl -v -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -T /your/path/file.ext "{presigned_url}"

Comment: To answer the $files question, yes.

Comment: _"What I'm not sure about is how to convert the CURL to PHP"_ - google "curl to php", you'll find a couple of services that help with automatic code conversion. (They don't always generate fully perfect code and sometimes it needs a bit of tweaking, but for something this simple, they should probably manage to produce something that'll work.)

Comment: This works:  exec('curl -v -H "Content-Type: "' . $audioMime . ' -T ' . $audio_path . ' "' . $presigned_url . '"'); Is this a cop out? I'm completely at a loss how to do as above.